# What is the right use of "using-declarations"?

Tags: c++

I was using this first -

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
my_cb = std::bind(&Myclass::handler, this, _1, _2);
```

The code worked fine, but cpplint complained and said I should use "using-declarations", I then changed the code to:

```
using _1 = std::placeholders::_1;
using _2 = std::placeholders::_2;
my_cb = std::bind(&Myclass::handler, this, _1, _2);
```

But now compiler complains:

```
error: ‘_1’ in namespace ‘std::placeholders’ does not name a type
```

What should be the right using-declarations?

**Update**
The replies so far suggest me to add back this line:
using namespace std::placeholders;

As I described, cpplint is not happy with using namespace, here is cpplint message:

```
Do not use namespace using-directives.  Use using-declarations instead.
```

Could you suggest how to do about it?

Comment: In this case, don't use std::bind and learn about [lambda functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). `using` only works when the right hand side is a know type at compile time, which is not the case in your code. `my_cb = std::bind(&Myclass::handler, this, _1, _2);` -> `my_cb = [&]{ this->handler(arg1, arg2);}`

Comment: IMHO this is (at least partly) opinion based. Some will agree with certain linter rules and some will disagree. My opinion; make up your own mind, don't just follow rules set by tools dogmatically.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::placeholders::_1`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) is not a type, it's an object of an unspecified type, thus `using` directive is not applicable to it. Just bring the `namespace std::placeholders` into a required scope

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
my_cb = std::bind(&Myclass::handler, this, _1, _2);
```

Comment: Can you check my update? The key is cpplint complaint.

Comment: @my_question Show a [mcve]. cpplint should not raise warnings if `using namespace std::placeholders` is used locally inside a function.

Comment: @273K If the using is inside a method, at least cpplint plus shows a warning, to.

Answer (score 1):

The message wants you to write

```
using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::placeholders::_2;
/*...*/
```

etc. This is what `using` declarations are. What you tried with syntax of the form `using /*...*/ = /*...*/;` are *type aliases*, a third meaning of `using` distinct from both *using directives* (`using namespace /*...*/;` and *using declarations* (`using /*...*/;`).

However, I don't think that is technically allowed at global namespace scope because names starting with an underscore are reserved there. Do it in a narrower scope.

The message is from clang-tidy and implements a particular rule in Google's style guides that flat out forbids any use of `using namespace`. However, the `std::placeholders` namespace is specifically designed to be used in this way and avoids making any other names visible. As long as it is used in a narrow scope (not at the global scope) I would consider it fine. Opinions on this rule will differ.